# C# Search txt file for missing text and if missing add text

Tags: c#

I have combined the content of three txt-files into one and now have to do the final touch.
I have managed to search for a comma and changed it to a dot. So far so good.
But...

Every now and then a line in that combined file reads "LENGTH " 
(Yes it is the word length followed by a space-character)

Sometimes that line is followed by a number... But... If that line is NOT followed by any number or other character at all it should be added the digit 0 (zero).

How do I solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far and do you really mean LENGHT and not LENGTH?

Comment: Simply read the file line by line, write each line to the target file, except if it's a "LENGTH " (or "LENGHT ") line without a digit, then append a "0" and write it to the target file. At which point of your code did you get stuck?

Comment: `LENGHT ` is at the end of the line? If there is no number after it it is still considered as correct? You know that it's a typo and should be `LENGTH `? You want to keep that typo?

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(target, File.ReadAllLines(source).Select(l => l == "LENGTH " ? "LENGTH 0" : l));`

Comment: Haha... Ok. I made a mistake in the spelling. I blame it on the fact that I am Swedish. :-)
I´ll try your suggestion right away, René.

Answer (score 0):

Read all lines of the file, raplace the wrong ones and write them back to the file:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
File.Delete(filePath);
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines.Select(l => l == "LENGTH " ? "LENGTH 0" : l));
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why? I see that a lot in reporting files. Length would mean the record count and is the last line in the report. If there are no records containt no count is given instead of 0

Comment: @TimSchmelter `LENGTH 123` or others won't be touched since nothing is replaced only if the complete line reads `LENGTH ` it will be exchanged for `LENGTH 0`

Comment: @RenéVogt I use .Net 4.6 in which (like in all other versions) `File.ReadAllLines` returns `string[]`. Have a look at the MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RenéVogt No, it doesnt. There is no overload, that accepts `IEnumerable<string>` only `string[]`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.100).aspx Look at the left side menu of the link you just posted.

Comment: You're right! Strangely, in the link I provided they are not displayed. I'll update my answer and remove the `ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stream the file line by line and replace the lines reading `LENGTH` with `LENGTH 0`:

```
string source = ...; // your file's name
string target = ...; // your target file's name

File.WriteAllLines(target, File.ReadAllLines(source).Select(l => l == "LENGTH " ? "LENGTH 0" : l));
```